# Can't change group permissions

Tags: group

I am currently having an issue which is preventing me from editing the group permissions for my '/media/rnetBackup/' directory. I have tried editing the permissions using nautilus and using

```
chgrp -R rnetshare /media/rnetBackup
```

but it doesn't have any effect.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what filesystem you are using; ii) show us the output of `ls -ld  /media/rnetBackup` before and after running the `chgrp` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chown` instead of `chgrp`. The syntax is `chown [OPTION]... [User]:[Group] file`.

For your case, you could do: `chown -R root:rnetshare /media/rnetBackup`

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking if the attributes of the directory are correctly set. For this, first do `lsattr`. It should give some output like this:

```
----i--------e-- /media/rnetBackup
```

If there is the character `i` in your output, it means the folder can not be edited. Just change the attributes in this case and it will be working fine:

```
sudo  chattr =e /media/rnetBackup
```